# How to check availability room reservation between check in and check out?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

need your help to check availability on room reservation. for the ilustration I have a tabel which have 3 coloumns such as room_number (varchar), check_in (date), check_out (date).

Then that table have one record data : 1212, 2014-04-19, 2014-04-22. Then in my PHP program I want to check availability in the same room number with Check in date = 2014-04-20 and Check Out date = 2014-04-23.

To check the room availability I use this query :

```
    select * from apartment where room_number = '$room_number' and ((date_in >= '2014-04-20' and date_out <= '2014-04-23') or (date_in <= '2014-04-20' and date_out >= '2014-04-23'));
```

According that date, supposed to be show the recorded data before in that table, but that query not show it and my PHP application still showing the message that that room still available to reserved. What is the correct query? Need your help.

Comment: You miss a ")" from the end.
select * from apartment where room_number = '$room_number' and ((date_in >= '2014-04-20' and date_out <= '2014-04-23') or (date_in <= '2014-04-20' and date_out >= '2014-04-23'));
(It's not an answer,just i noticed it)

Comment: Thank's bro.. I've been update it.

Comment: `select * from apartment where room_number = '$room_number' and (date_in between '2014-04-20' and '2014-04-23') or (date_out between '2014-04-20' and '2014-04-23');`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from apartment a
where 
a.room_number = '$room_number' 
and not exists  (select * from apartment a2 
                 where a2.room_number = a1.room_number
                   and   (      (date_in >= '2014-04-20' and date_out < '2014-04-23')
                         or     (date_in <= '2014-04-20' and date_out > '2014-04-23')
                         )
                  )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date type for the case of check in and check out. But consider a case

Your room is vacated on morning on 20th April 2014.when you consider date only that room can't able to give any other guests .So in my oppinion its better conside to use timestamp instead of dates

Coming to question you can implement a query something like this

```
select room_number from apartment as ap
where room_number not in 
            (
              select room_number
              from apartment as ap1 
              where (DATE_BEGIN >= @start and DATE_BEGIN < @end)
                or (DATE_END >= @start and DATE_END < @end)
             )
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be the query that you need

```
SELECT * FROM apartment WHERE room_number = '$room_number' AND date_in <= '$date_out' AND date_out >= '$date_in';
```

Also I believe that we shouldn't make things complicated using "BETWEEN". So if you really consider about room availability checking in practical manner, this should be the correct answer. If you want to assign this query to a variable, use double quotation to wrap the query.

Comment: Queries containing strings that come from the application, or even the end user of that application, should never be the correct answer, as such queries are widely open for SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase I just wanted to provide the query logic to check availability and developer should know how to prevent security issues.